# Multi user application attach multi accounts

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript

I want to make multiaccount application like instagram (attach another account and switch from one account to another)
For this I'm using Laravel for backend API and angular for frontend.
What is the best way to do that?
With JWT token?

- Logging to application with User1 -> receive a JWT token and store it to localstorage for using from frontend
- Attach another account (User2) to this one with this flow: logging to User2 using a specific form -> receive a JWT token -> store it to database for User1 in a table like that:

```
    |users|
    id

    |users_attached_accounts|
    id 
    user_id
    attached_account_id

    |attached_accounts|
    id
    account_id
    username
    token
```

In frontend I switch to User1 or User2 by using user token and backend recognize which user by token used.

Comment: This approach would be the one I'd use myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Laravel MultiAuth library to create multiple users in one application.https://bitfumes.github.io/laravel-multiauth/